# P tag doesn't move down on small screens

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, css-position

I added a tagline near the logo and everything looks fine on widescreen

[image]

But when I narrow the screen the text moves in  a wierd way

**I want it to move below the logo and move the menu down**

[image]

I tried editing the responsive css files, adding a `display: block;` , playing with the `positions` nothing seems to work.

here's the css:

```
#s5_header_wrap, #s5_footer_area_inner2, #s5_breadcrumb_font_wrap, #s5_component_wrap_inner {
padding-left:30px;
padding-right:30px;
position: relative;
}

#logo_tagline{

    font-family: "Verdana";
    color: #1f1f1f;
    font-size: 13px;
    position: relative; 
    height: 100px;
}

#logo_tagline p{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    padding-top: 15px;
    height: 100px;
    line-height: 23px
}


#logo_tagline{

        font-family: "Verdana";
        color: #1f1f1f;
        font-size: 13px;
        position: relative; 
        height: 100px;
    }

    #logo_tagline p{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        padding-top: 15px;
        height: 100px;
        line-height: 23px
    }
```

and the html: the `logo_tagline` is inside of `s5_header_wrap`

Comment: Can you post the html?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a static `head` element (or whatever that is) then you can try

```
element {
  min-width: someval; 
}
```

Using min-width will specify, that this element must have this width at any code, even if the browse window is scrolled!

If you want to change the whole layout, then you might consider using CSS3 Media Query

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 500px) { // if screen size 500px;
   /* change the properties so that 
    * logo comes above, and other elements
    * such as menu and text shows below it..*/
}
```

Comment: I edited the question, I want it to work reponsivly and move below the logo in small screens and move the menu down

Comment: Check the answer, you will need css media query to check the screen size, and change the properties depending on the screen size! This will be handy for you..

Answer (score 0):

I can't see your markup, but here is a simple layout and style that should help you solve this problem.  I think the magic may be in the `clear:both;` for you.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            * {margin: 0; }
            .header {background-color: #eee;}
            .logo {
                background-color: ddd;
                border-right: 1px solid #333;
                width: 200px;
                height: 50px;
                float:left;
                margin: 0 20px 20px 0;
            }
            .header p {line-hieght: 20px;}
            .cf { clear: both;}
            ul {
             list-style: none;
             margin: 0;
             padding: 0;
             }
            ul li {
                display: inline-block;
                padding: 0 20px;
                border-right: 1px solid #333;
            }
            .navigation {
                background-color: #ccc;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="header">
            <div class="logo">DebutInvest</div>
            <p>THis is some text that will wrap when needed blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</p>
            <p>THis is some text that will wrap when needed blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</p>
            <p>THis is some text that will wrap when needed blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</p>
            <div class="cf"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="navigation">
            <ul>
                <li>BigWord1</li> 
                <li>BigWord2</li>
                <li>BigWord3</li>
                <li>BigWord4</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The logo (or its container) is floating left I suspect.

If that's true you can either give the logo `float: none` or give the tag line `clear: both` on small screens.